# App Gateway, Unable to create health probe with powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-application-gateway, probe

I'm currently experiencing an issue while attempting to create a health probe using PowerShell. I've already successfully created multiple health probes through the portal.

When I execute the command, I don't receive any error messages. However, upon checking the portal, I cannot find the health probe that I attempted to create using PowerShell. Interestingly, I am able to create a health probe with the same name via the portal.

Any assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I used the command:

```
$getgw =  Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name Nametest -ResourceGroupName RGtest

# Create the probe object that will check health 

$probeApi = Add-AzApplicationGatewayProbeConfig -ApplicationGateway $getgw -Name $probeNameApi -Protocol Http -Path '/api/test' -Interval 30 -Timeout 120 -UnhealthyThreshold 3
```

Comment: Type $probeApi in powershell and see if it contains any data.  Specifically see if it returns a status of 200 OK or a 400/500 error.

Comment: @Darin I've tried with this but not working.

Comment: @jdweng this command shows a table of AppGW info

Comment: If you are not getting any data (and no errors), it usually means the backend query is not returning any results.  How are you determining that you are unable to create the probes?

Answer (score 0):

To create health probe in PowerShell, make use of below command.

```c
# Load the application gateway resource into a PowerShell variable by using Get-AzApplicationGateway.
$getgw =  Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name <ApplicationGatewayName>  -ResourceGroupName <RGName>

# Create the probe object that will check health at http://contoso.com/path/path.htm
$probe = Add-AzApplicationGatewayProbeConfig -ApplicationGateway $getgw -Name <HealthyprobeName> -Protocol Http -HostName 'contoso.com' -Path '/path/custompath.htm' -Interval 30 -Timeout 120 -UnhealthyThreshold 8

# Set the backend HTTP settings to use the new probe
$getgw = Set-AzApplicationGatewayBackendHttpSettings -ApplicationGateway $getgw -Name $getgw.BackendHttpSettingsCollection.name -Port 80 -Protocol Http -CookieBasedAffinity Disabled  -RequestTimeout 120

# Save the application gateway with the configuration changes
Set-AzApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $getgw
```

***Output***:

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal after executing script, health probe is created successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: @Imran In your case, this is the first probe you are creating, try with the same command to create the second one. In my case I already have multiple probes already created from the portal. Also, did you create the Backend settings before this command? In my case I need to create a new one for this probe. Thanks!

Comment: I can able to create multiple probes in PowerShell code [output](https://i.imgur.com/bUx9df5.png) in portal check [this](https://i.imgur.com/PqBs8Ii.png)

Comment: Thank you it worked, I had to create a backendsettings too

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, the mistake that I was doing is creating a probe and backendsettings and then save the application gateway.

The solution is that I had to save the application gateway with the command:
Set-AzApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $getgw

after each scope added:

```
# Load the application gateway resource into a PowerShell variable by using 
Get-AzApplicationGateway.
$getgw =  Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name appGWName -ResourceGroupName RGName

# Create the probe object that will check health at http://contoso.com/path/path.htm
$probe = Add-AzApplicationGatewayProbeConfig -ApplicationGateway $getgw -Name testprobe01 -Protocol Http -HostName 'contoso.com' -Path '/path/custompath.htm' -Interval 30 -Timeout 120 -UnhealthyThreshold 8
# Save the application gateway with the configuration changes
Set-AzApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $getgw
$probe = get-AzApplicationGatewayProbeConfig -ApplicationGateway $getgw -Name testprobe01 

# Set the backend HTTP settings to use the new probe
$Bes = Add-AzApplicationGatewayBackendHttpSettings -ApplicationGateway $getgw -
```

Name testbackendhttpsettings -Port 80 -Protocol Http -CookieBasedAffinity Disabled -Probe $probe -RequestTimeout 180
# Save the application gateway with the configuration changes
Set-AzApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $getgw